# Connect to a specific Wifi SSID programmatically

Tags: android, connection, android-wifi

I am working on a network specific app and I see there are a few apps on play store that connect/disconnect and enable/disable wifi programmatically. I want to do the same.
Since, most of the methods are deprecated and PlayStore requires app to be built for android 29+, I am not able to connect to SSID programatically to get internet connection for all apps. Need help with Android 5 - 12.
Is there a way to manage wifi programmatically or anything related like a certificate needed or something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is no longer possible programmatically on non-rooted device (I think since Android 10). The correct way to go is requesting the user to toggle/connect/disconnect WiFi (there is a new dedicated dialog for it t)